# Angular 1.4.8 Route Params htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, .htaccess

im having a problem when trying to refresh my page in second level, when has set a parameter by routing angular like this:

> localhost/ADMIN/page/1

where

> localhost/BASE_FOLDER/ROUTE/ROUT_PARAM

So, i have this defined in my routing app:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {
          templateUrl: 'template/home.html',
          controller: 'homeController'
        })
        .when('/page', {
          templateUrl: 'template/page-list.html',
          controller: 'pageListController'
        })
        .when('/page/:id', {
          templateUrl: 'template/page-details.html',
          controller: 'pageDetailsController'
        })
        .when('/', {
          redirectTo: 'home'
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '404'
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    }]);
```

So the problem of refresh only has an error when is in /page/:id for rewrite rules im sure, but i cant find the error, hope you can see it, thank you.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ADMIN/

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Redirect urls without a trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

This is the error, but cant see it. The page display all wi

[image: error console]

[image: image testing with other url, not 'page', but has the same error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problema was setting the base tag in the index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    ....
    <base href="/ADMIN/" >
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

The position of the 'base' tag is so important, because it need be set at the first line of the head tag, like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/ADMIN/" >
    ....        
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

And solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like this might be the problem:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

^ says "match anything"

- means "take no action"

[L] means "last rule" i.e. stop processing RewriteRules after this point

This [L] combined with an 'any' match will cause your final re-write below to never execute:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Comment: so, i replaced this -> "RewriteRule ^ - [L]" by the line you give me, and doesnt work, now it doesnt load any css from start. :S

Comment: I found the problem, it is so important where to set base='/ADMIN/' tag  in index.html, you have to set it at start or it will give a error